# Malformed template tag at line 23: "else (page_num > topics.number|add:'-3') and (page_num < topics.number|add:'3')"

Tags: python, django

I am using the following function based view to create a pagination. There are no bugs in this views, but the way I am using the context in template creates problem specially when I am adding `{% else page_num > topics.number|add:'-3' and page_num < topics.number|add:'3' %}` in templates.

**Views.py**

```
def board_topics(request, pk):
    board = get_object_or_404(Board, pk=pk)
    queryset = board.topics.annotate(replies_count=Count('posts') - 1).order_by(
        '-last_updated')
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(queryset, 10)

    try:
        topics = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        topics = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        topics = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request, 'board/board_topics.html', {'board': board, 'topics': topics})
```

and the **`template`** here:

```
    {% for page_num in topics.paginator.page_range %}
    {% if topics.number == page_num %}
            {{ page_num }}
    {% else page_num > topics.number|add:'-3' and page_num < topics.number|add:'3' %}
        <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_num }}">{{ page_num }}</a>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

If in template I replace `{% else page_num > topics.number|add:'-3' and page_num < topics.number|add:'3' %}` with `{% else %}` it works totally fine, but I need the first one to work since I don't want to show tons of pagination number on my page if there are thousands of topics.

Can you help me out with this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you template you're giving condition to `else` which won't work as it only executes what is not satisfied by `if`.

An else statement contains the block of code that executes if the conditional expression in the if statement resolves to 0 or a FALSE value. The else statement is an optional statement and there could be at most only one else statement following if.

So you need to use `{% elif %}` here.

**`Template`**

```
{% for page_num in topics.paginator.page_range %}
{% if topics.number == page_num %}
        {{ page_num }}
{% elif page_num > topics.number|add:'-3' and page_num < topics.number|add:'3' %}
    <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_num }}">{{ page_num }}</a>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Or you can always use multiple `if` blocks

```
{% for page_num in topics.paginator.page_range %}
{% if topics.number == page_num %}
        {{ page_num }}
{% endif %}
{% if page_num > topics.number|add:'-3' and page_num < topics.number|add:'3' %}
    <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_num }}">{{ page_num }}</a>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```